# Changing style of active thumbnail image Ninja Slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider

For some reason I can't target / Select image in span in div and change it when clicked or active and toggle the rest off.

So in other words there is a span over the image, when I rollover or click on it it should change styles, why you not change style bro?

Here is an example of exactly what I need to happen: http://www.menucool.com/slider/jquery-slideshow

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.light>img')
  .mouseover(function(event) {
  $(event.target).addClass('thumb-img');
   })
  .mouseout(function(event) {
  $(event.target).removeClass('thumb-img');
  })
  .click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).toggleClass('thumb-img');



    });
   });

  </script>
```

Here is my html:

```
<!--start-->
<div id="ninja-slider">
    <div class="slider-inner">
        <ul>
            <li><!--Video one-->
                <div class="video">
                   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/8EO7byfYfAQ?enablejsapi=1&start=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li><!--Video two-->
                <div class="video">
                    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e_CQv0zoDM8?enablejsapi=1&start=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1" wmode="Opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>

            </li>
            <li><!--Video three-->
                <div class="video">
                   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/crkig25K7NQ?enablejsapi=1&start=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                </li>
                <li><!--Video four-->
               <div class="video">
                   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T5voTNy8fpg?enablejsapi=1&start=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                 <a class="ns-img" href="http://176.32.230.2/darynhigginson.com/r-week-slider/img/4.jpg"></a>
                <div class="video-playbutton-layer"></div>
                </li>
                <li><!--Video five-->
                 <div class="video">
                   <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/efftckypcXk?enablejsapi=1&start=0&rel=0&showinfo=0&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
              <a class="ns-img" href="http://176.32.230.2/darynhigginson.com/r-week-slider/img/5.jpg"></a>
                 <div class="video-playbutton-layer"></div>
                </li>

          <!--  <li>
                <div class="video">
                    <video controls data-autoplay="false">
                        <source src="img/mcvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                    </video>
                </div>
                <a class="ns-img" href="img/3.jpg"></a>
                <div class="video-playbutton-layer"></div>
            </li>-->

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="thumbs">
         <span class="light"  onclick="nslider.playVideo(0)"><img  src="http://176.32.230.2/darynhigginson.com/r-week-slider/img/1.jpg" /><span class="playvideo"></span>  <div class="thumb-description"><!--<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4><p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>--></div></span>
        <span class="light"  onclick="nslider.playVideo(1)"><img  src="http://176.32.230.2/darynhigginson.com/r-week-slider/img/2.jpg" /><span class="playvideo"></span>  <div class="thumb-description"><!--<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4><p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>--></div></span>
        <span   class="light" onclick="nslider.playVideo(2)"><img  src="http://176.32.230.2/darynhigginson.com/r-week-slider/img/3.jpg" /><span class="playvideo"></span>  <div class="thumb-description"><!--<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4><p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>--></div></span>

          <span  class="light"  onclick="nslider.playVideo(3)"><img  src="http://176.32.230.2/darynhigginson.com/r-week-slider/img/4.jpg" /><span class="playvideo"></span>  <div class="thumb-description"><!--<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4><p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>--></div></span>
           <span  class="light"  onclick="nslider.playVideo(4)"><img  src="http://176.32.230.2/darynhigginson.com/r-week-slider/img/5.jpg" /><span class="playvideo"></span>
           <div class="thumb-description"><!--<h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4><p>consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>--></div>
           </span>

    </div>
</div>
<!--end-->
```

For the hover I am using css which works fine:

```
  div#thumbs > span img {
   opacity:0.8;
   }

  div#thumbs > span:hover img{
   opacity:1;
    }
```

But I need the image to  STAY "ACTIVE" when clicked and rest to NOT be active.

/*<<<<<------This is the original style I want to add this------>*/

```
 div#thumbs img.thumb-img {
  opacity:1;
  border:6px solid #666666;

  }
```

Pleeeeease help, I'm in trouble. I am a noob

Comment: you are using what slider?

Comment: you need to find first if that is active or not, then the other img, you need to put `:hover`

Comment: I am using menu-cool / Ninja Slider (Video slider). I need the image to stay active when I click @mmativ

Comment: the demo, is ok, you got the `active` state when you click it.

Comment: just follow the documentation.

Comment: the jquery is not adding the class to the image tag, so it doesn't stay active once mouse out. (-_-') ??

Comment: you mean you want to add `opacity:1` on all `img`?

Comment: yeah sorry, so the opacity is 0.8 and when you click or rollover it goes to 1.0

Answer (score 0):

add this code to your `css`

```
#thumbnail-slider ul li{
   opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: better if you show your code, because we cant fix this if we dont know the exact code, thats answer is based on  http://www.menucool.com/slider/jquery-slideshow coding.

Comment: Thank you I have added the full html for the slider in my question

Comment: btw, this project are online or not?